# ASP.Net Async SQL Query and Ajax UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, sql, ajax, asynchronous, updatepanel

Here's the scenario that I'm having trouble with...

I have a SQL stored proc that I want to execute and while waiting for it to complete (it will take several seconds) I want to update a label inside an update panel with a counter.

The code below does not update the updatePanel when I call its update method and I'm not sure why. It'll only update the panel once the entire call has finished.

Any suggestions?

ASPX:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</form>
```

Code-Behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

'assume code for sql command is already setup and the stored proc does indeed execute

Dim count As Integer = 0
Dim result As IAsyncResult = cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery()
While Not result.IsCompleted
    Label1.Text = count
    UpdatePanel1.Update()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
    count += 1
End While

End Sub
```

So for example, the stored proc takes 10 seconds to execute, I end up seeing the number 20 in the label (essentially 2 per second) but I want to see it show 0, then update to 1, then update to 2, etc, etc... the UpdatePanel only seems to update once, not each time the `UpdatePanel1.Update()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Since the operation is asynchronous, [await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx#BKMK_AsyncandAwait) would give you the following advantages over sleep:

- State information
- Status updates
- Avoid possible infinite loop if the operation never completes